# call ccTouchesBegan even when i touch a ccMenuItem

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a `CCMenu` with `CCMenuItems` that I add on a `CCLayer`. When I click on the `CCMenuItems`, my `CCTouchesBegan` doesn't fire up.

How can I call this method also when I touch my menu items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CCMenu registers as targeted touch delegate and swallows touches on menu items. You can try to create your subclass of CCMenu and override it `registerWithTouchDispatcher` method like this

```
-(void) registerWithTouchDispatcher
{
    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:kCCMenuTouchPriority swallowsTouches:NO];
}
```

This should work as you want, but maybe can cause other problems with menu behavior.